# Canon Printer job hang on "Processing"

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing, canon, cups-lpd

I have Canon LBP-3300 and installed `cndrvcups-capt_2.70-1_amd64.deb` and `cndrvcups-common_3.20-1_amd64.deb` without any problem.

LBP3300 is showing on Printers:

[image: Printers settings]

But when I want to print the job hang on Processing:

[image: Print job hang on Processing]

I went to the `http://localhost:631/printers/` and it shows `Processing - "Sending data to printer."`

[image: Print job hang on Processing]

Result of `tail -f /var/log/syslog` when printer is ON and USB is connected:

```
Jan 27 13:26:55 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6276]: remove /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1
Jan 27 13:26:55 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6276]: URI of detected printer: usb://Canon/LBP3300?serial=00001184PI9N, normalized: canon lbp3300 serial 00001184pi9n
Jan 27 13:26:55 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6276]: URI of print queue: usb://Canon/LBP3300?serial=00001184PI9N, normalized: canon lbp3300 serial 00001184pi9n
Jan 27 13:26:55 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6276]: Queue ipp://localhost/printers/LBP3300 has matching device URI
Jan 27 13:26:55 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6276]: Disabled printer ipp://localhost/printers/LBP3300 as the corresponding device was unplugged or turned off
Jan 27 13:26:55 ice-system systemd[1]: printer.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Jan 27 13:26:55 ice-system systemd[1]: Stopped target Printer.
Jan 27 13:26:55 ice-system kernel: [ 2450.174875] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp5s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c327:77e1:783a:4ca2 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=958574 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Jan 27 13:26:55 ice-system kernel: [ 2450.174898] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp5s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c327:77e1:783a:4ca2 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=39070 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Jan 27 13:26:55 ice-system kernel: [ 2450.185099] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp5s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c327:77e1:783a:4ca2 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=958574 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system kernel: [ 2481.527150] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system kernel: [ 2481.681297] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04a9, idProduct=267e
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system kernel: [ 2481.681300] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system kernel: [ 2481.681302] usb 1-1: Product: Canon CAPT USB Device
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system kernel: [ 2481.681304] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Canon
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system kernel: [ 2481.681305] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00001184PI9N
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system kernel: [ 2481.682776] usblp 1-1:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 5 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04A9 pid 0x267E
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1"
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system systemd[1]: Starting Automatic USB/Bluetooth printer setup (-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1a.7-usb1-1\x2d1)...
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system systemd[1]: Reached target Printer.
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6301]: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6301]: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6301]: MFG:Canon MDL:LBP3300 SERN:- serial:00001184PI9N
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system kernel: [ 2481.772149] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp5s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c327:77e1:783a:4ca2 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=958574 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Jan 27 13:27:26 ice-system kernel: [ 2481.772167] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp5s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c327:77e1:783a:4ca2 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=39070 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Jan 27 13:27:31 ice-system kernel: [ 2486.746164] usblp1: removed
Jan 27 13:27:31 ice-system kernel: [ 2486.749422] usblp 1-1:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 5 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04A9 pid 0x267E
Jan 27 13:27:31 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6301]: URI contains USB serial number
Jan 27 13:27:31 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6301]: URI match: usb://Canon/LBP3300?serial=00001184PI9N
Jan 27 13:27:31 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6301]: URI of detected printer: usb://Canon/LBP3300?serial=00001184PI9N, normalized: canon lbp3300 serial 00001184pi9n
Jan 27 13:27:31 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6301]: URI of print queue: usb://Canon/LBP3300?serial=00001184PI9N, normalized: canon lbp3300 serial 00001184pi9n
Jan 27 13:27:31 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6301]: Queue ipp://localhost/printers/LBP3300 has matching device URI
Jan 27 13:27:31 ice-system udev-configure-printer[6301]: Re-enabled printer ipp://localhost/printers/LBP3300
Jan 27 13:27:31 ice-system systemd[1]: Started Automatic USB/Bluetooth printer setup (-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1a.7-usb1-1\x2d1).
Jan 27 13:27:31 ice-system kernel: [ 2486.909373] usblp1: removed
```

Result of `lpinfo -v` when printer is ON and USB is connected:

```
network http
network ipp14
network beh
network lpd
network socket
network ipp
network ipps
direct hp
direct ccp
network https
direct usb://Canon/LBP3300?serial=00001184PI9N
direct hpfax
```

Result of `lsusb` when printer is ON and USB is connected:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04a9:267e Canon, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: so I am wondering if this is not the same problem as here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000452/why-is-canon-lbp-1120-not-working-after-re-boot .. namely that you need to turn on the ccpd daemon each time you boot the computer; use the command `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start` and see if that gets things going;

Comment: @pdc It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: we find running the latest drivers is helpful; we are using cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb and cndrvcups-common_3.21-1_amd64.deb  It was issued 15th May 2017 from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html .. is this just a recent install .. when did you install .. has it ever printed ... the sort of stuff that is helpful to know ..

Comment: did you register LBP3300 in the ccpd daemon setup file: eg sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP3300 -o /dev/usb/lp0 or lp1 as I see your printout listed lp1  ........ you installed the drivers but you need to register the printer and register it with the ccpd daemon

Comment: @pdc It doesn't work either. When I was on the Ubuntu 14.04, like 2 years ago, I could print :(

Comment: when I do `lpinfo -v` I get ... amongst other things ..  network beh
network https
network lpd
direct ccp
network ipps
direct cnijusb:/dev/usb/lp0
direct cnijusb:/dev/usb/lp1
network ipp
network http
direct ecblp:/var/run/ecblp0
network smb
network ipp14
direct usb://Canon/LBP3100/LBP3108/LBP3150?serial=0000B18B4GVx

direct cnusb:/dev/usb/lp1
direct hp
direct parallel:/dev/lp0
direct hpfax
network dnssd://EPSON%20XP-410%20Series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-ac182683d8f6
network 
network lpd://192.168.1.105:515/PASSTHRU

Comment: and I am wondering if `lsusb` shows the Canon .. eg I get `Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04a9:26db Canon, Inc.`

Comment: the comments field doesn't seem to allow one to use the ENTER key to create paragraphs; so the printout from lpinfo is all mixed together

Comment: @pdc added result of `lsusb` to the question

Comment: @pdc I don't know why but it seems I have new item on `lpinfo -v`. added that to the question

Answer (score 1):

Canon would say you need to do 4 things for the CAPT driver in linux

1) install drivers

2) Register the printer (PPD) with the print spooler.

3) Register the printer in the ccpd daemon setup file.

4) start up ccpd daemon

1) get the latest drivers from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html and click to download and save  linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz

2) `sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP3300 -m CNCUPSLBP3300CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 –E`  .....*note this is all one line* ......

3)`sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP3300 -o /dev/usb/lp0` and that assumes only one usb printer

4) `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start`

and for me that has worked on two separate 16.04 installs

Comment: didn't work :( I did the same installation before.

Comment: so with the LBP plugged in; and turned on; if you look in /dev/usb I wonder how many devices you see ....... I am wondering if you used lp0 or lp1 to register with the ccpd daemon ..

Comment: I have only `hiddev0` inside `/dev/usb` when the printer turned On or Off. I have only one printer and tried ccpd with both lp0 and lp1.

Comment: so if I issue the command `cd /dev/usb` with printers on; and then `ls` to list the contents, I get `lp0  lp1` ....... if you get hiddev0 from that same command, surely one should try `sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP3300 -o /dev/usb/hiddev0` as the ccpd registration command? Why would you get hiddev0 ... is this a standard desktop computer?

Comment: yes, the `ls ` showing only `hiddev0`. I added custom usb device by `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="267e", ATTRS{serial}=="00001184PI9N", SYMLINK+="usb/lbp3300"` and suddenly the `ls` showing `lp1` and `lbp3300`. and the problem still exists. even with `lp1` or `lbp3300` that i created. I think it's time to give up. maybe it's CUPS bug. Thank you for your time.