# Why is canon lbp-1120 not working after re-boot?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I managed to get the canon lbp-1120 to work on Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) using the 32 bit driver as suggested here [LBP1120 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459354/lbp1120-on-ubuntu-14-04). However once I shutdown or re-boot, it no longer works, even though the printer is showing as installed. Is it possible that on re-boot, it is defaulting back to the 64bit driver and if so, how do I delete that driver?

Comment: your printer uses an extra layer; called the ccpd daemon; so you need to start that each time; we have the an LBP too; it works well; I confess each time I start the computer; I open the terminal; find the command; (using the up arrow ..) and activate the ccpd daemon. The command is `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start` and if you edit rc.local you can place it there I believe; to automate; but I have never sat down to do that ..

Comment: that is great; delighted to hear it works; I just open the terminal each time I start and use the up arrow to find the command ..

Comment: After installing os update, i now get this message when I run sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start: "Starting /usr/sbin/ccpd: start-stop-daemon: unable to stat /usr/sbin/ccpd (No such file or directory)". Looks like the file has dissappeared! Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't understand that: you are telling the system to look in `/etc/init.d` which is where ccpd is; and it seems to be going off to `/usr/sbin` and then telling you it can't find ccpd there; which ain't surprising; as ccpd ain't there; it is one folder down in the etc folder; so you just ran the command `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start`  ......... in the terminal? All I can suggest is copying this command from here; opening a terminal; and trying again ..

Comment: Strange indeed. I tried your suggestion but no joy.

Comment: I see I have a ccpd in our usr/sbin ........ so linux was being logical; I don't know what in an update would "upset the apple cart" but 1) you could delete the existing entry in the PRINTERS folder for your LBP .. and reinstall but perhaps first .............. 2) I wonder if you copy ccpd to /usr/sbin with the command `sudo cp /etc/init.d/ccpd /usr/sbin` then look inside /usr/sbin to see if ccpd is there `ls /usr/sbin` then if it is there now, try `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start` again ...........

Comment: I'l try that thanks. It may have been apt-get -f install which I was prompted to run.

Comment: After trying your suggestion I got this message: Starting /usr/sbin/ccpd: Usage: ccpd {start|stop|status} but printer is still not working. Should I try your other suggestion to delete and re-install?

Comment: Problem solved here https://askubuntu.com/questions/459354/lbp1120-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: ...... em ...... which bit of the above post worked please?

Comment: Answer 1 Installing the capt driver and Configuring LBP1120