# Canon LBP2900B Printer is not printing

Tags: printing, canon

I am using Ubuntu 21.04. The printer was working with this Ubuntu version. Recently I tried to print and printer is not going beyond processing step.
I tried as advised on this platform, but couldn't solve my problem. As the system is dual boot, I have to switch to windows to print.
My printer: Canon LBP 2900B.

what else information do you guys need to help me?
Kindly note that I am not a hardware or software tech, but I can follow if guided properly.

So far what have I tried to resolve?

My first try: (post link: [Printer is stuck at processing status](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088858/printer-is-stuck-at-processing-status))

To Pause the cups server. I use this code:

```
sudo service cups stop
```

The next step was to edit the following file: printer.conf (/etc/cups/printers.conf file)
But the file was locked and it says that I don't have permission to open. (note the icon was Crossmark rather lock)

My second try:

Then I tried this suggestion:
Pause cups server (same as above)

```
sudo service cups stop
```

The next step was to edit the following file: cupsd.conf (/etc/cups/cupsd.conf)
But the same was the outcome, as the system didn't allow me to edit/open the file.

My third try: (post link: [Canon Printer job hang on "Processing"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000358/canon-printer-job-hang-on-processing))

```
sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 –E
```

It gave me some list. (screenshot attached)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWn31.png)

```
sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0

Error:
sudo: /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin: command not found
```

My fourth try: (post link: [Can't configure Canon LBP2900b printer in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303064/cant-configure-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-20-04))

I tried this script:

```
wget https://github.com/hieplpvip/canon_printer/raw/master/canon_lbp_setup.sh
chmod +x canon_lbp_setup.sh
./canon_lbp_setup.sh

Error:
Creating a rule for the printer
Running ccpd
Failed to restart ccpd.service: Unit ccpd.service not found.
./canon_lbp_setup.sh: line 318: /root/Desktop/LBP2900.desktop: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/root/Desktop/LBP2900.desktop': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access '/root/Desktop/LBP2900.desktop': No such file or directory
Installation completed. Press any key to exit
```

So I tried manual installation:
Using script:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Error:

```
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/arch-new': Permission denied
```

Failed to resolve the issue.

I can provide remote access to my desktop to resolve this issue.

Will fresh install of Ubuntu 21.04 resolve the issue?

One more thing I noticed is that the driver version is 1.5 and there is a newer version 2.20 available at the canon site.

I downloaded it and tried to update the driver, but the three options to choose the driver from were: 1) Select from the database, which recommends me to the old version and I cannot see the new version. (Obviously, I downloaded and saved it at a different location) How do I update it?

2. PPD files from the drive. (Which I couldn't find)
3. Search for a printer driver to download. (when search for Canon LBP2900, it returned no matches found).

Status: Unresolved

Thanks.

Comment: Please tell what you "tried as advised on this platform" and where you found it maybe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't configure Canon LBP2900b printer in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303064/cant-configure-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-20-04)

Comment: These are the posts that I tried to resolve: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088858/printer-is-stuck-at-processing-status and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000358/canon-printer-job-hang-on-processing

Comment: My system didn't allow me to change the printer.conf and cupsd.conf as suggested in the posts. I didn't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Please check my link above, no need to change any confs, at least not manually

Comment: Can't configure the Canon LBP2900b printer in 20.04 This I tried but the result was the same. The printer didn't proceed from processing.

Comment: Please **edit your question** and tell us exactly what you tried and where it failed? Did you use the install script from that github link? Please, not in the comments.

Comment: I got the script from GitHub and installed it via terminal. It was installed and the printer did say ready, but when the job was submitted, it failed to proceed from the processing step. as If the system hangs.

Comment: Please edit your question and add everything you tried with links where you get this from. Please, not in the comments. Future readers won't read all comments...

Comment: Printer is getting installed, but it is not printing the job. It gets stuck at processing step. I am trying to resolve this issue and couldn't find a way to resolve it. I can provide remote access to the system if anyone willing to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: I did not mean that you post links to what you tried, but the exact steps including error messages.

Comment: @pLumo I have edited the post and as advised by you I tried my best to explain the steps and errors. Thanks for the suggestions and supports

Comment: How do I solve  the printing problem?

Comment: How come there is no one to resolve the issue? Please access my system and resolve the said issue. Thanks